# Popularity of sentence patterns books in Japanese

Tags: sentence, learning

Why are sentence patterns is a such popular topic in Japanese learning? Comparing with other languages, I found that there are way more books on sentence patterns in Japanese language than in, say, Chinese or Korean.

Is there anything particular of the language that makes compiling sentence patterns useful?

Comment: Most people here don't have any familiarity with resources for studying other languages, so it would probably help to quantify things a bit more. I also had not noticed that "sentence pattern" books were particularly abundant among Japanese resources. Can you give examples of what you mean?

Comment: @Leebo. It is only a personal observation. But if you do a search on amazon, "sentence patterns" for example, the overwhelming results will be for Japanese. They even have various sentence patterns dictionaries.

Comment: Aren't most of those a series written by one author?

Comment: @aguijonazo. A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Sentence Patterns by Naoko Chino; Japanese Sentence Pattern Dictionary by Yuriko Sunakawa; Japanese Expression Sentence Pattern Dictionary by Makoto Meguro; Japanese Sentence Patterns for Effective Communication by Taeko Kamiya; Japanese Sentence Patterns for JLPT N5: by Clay Boutwell and Yumi Boutwell; Japanese Grammar: A Workbook for Self-Study: Essential Sentence Patterns for Everyday Communication  by Masahiro Tanimori. Well, you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s a translation for 文型, a term often used in the Japanese education as a second/foreign language (as well as in the English education in Japan).

> ぶんけい【文型】
>
> 語や語群が文中でどのように配置されているかを，文の構造や語句の機能の上から形式化して分類した文の型。

For example, learners are taught the following as two different 文型.

> ＿＿＿に　＿＿＿が　あります。

> ＿＿＿は　＿＿＿に　あります。

The difference could be very difficult to teach without introducing these “sentence patterns.” You would have to explain how が and は are different, how word order changes the focus of the sentence, etc., but that would put off most beginners.

The learners are advised to memorize these patterns as they are without worrying too much about individual pieces. That’s despite the fact that the following “patterns” are also possible.

> ＿＿＿が　＿＿＿に　あります。

> ＿＿＿に　＿＿＿は　あります。

The apparent popularity of publications on “sentence patterns” may be a reflection of this tendency, or tradition, in the Japanese education as a second/foreign language.

文型 in English (as taught in Japan) are much more limited. They mostly correspond to such basic patterns as SV, SVC, SVO, SVOO, and SVOC.

Comment: Thank you. So there is nothing particular of Japanese language that warrants sentence patterns compilations. I imagine, at the risk of oversimplifying,  that teachers of Japanese as a second language detect a gap between dictionaries and grammar books. I am not convinced that this is really the case. One of the examples is あいだ/間. Most dictionaries would have both definitions and examples for this expression.

Comment: @Beni - What do you mean by "both definitions"? あいだ and ま?

Comment: あいだ is the kunyomi of 間. You could either look up あいだ or 間 in dictionaries where you would get a definition, something like "ものとものとの間.すきま.へだたり" and examples such as "夏休みのあいだにほんをたくさん読みすま” essentially the same information as in sentence patterns compilations. So I don't really see the reason why these compilations are so popular. Sure there are cases that neither dictionaries nor grammar books explain well, but this happens to all languages where one would need specialized dictionaries or something like Fowler's English usage. But dictionaries of sentence patterns?

Comment: @Beni - ものとものの間 is not even a sentence. If dictionaries of “sentence patterns” list such entries, I would say the name is misleading. The difference between 〜の間〜する and 〜の間に〜する might be better explained in a dictionary of “sentence patterns” than a normal dictionary. I don’t know how they are different from grammar books, though.

Comment: ＠aguijonazo. I got the definition from 漢字辞典 by 藤堂明保. One grammar book has four categories for あいだ/あいだに depending if it goes with a noun, adjective or verb etc.